# How to write isNumeric function in Golang?

Tags: go

I want to check if a string is numeric.

For example:

- `"abcd123"` should return `false`.
- `"1.4"` or `"240"` should return `true`.

I thought about using `ParseInt` and `ParseFloat` (from the `strconv` package), but am not sure if that is the right way.

Comment: You could do it with ParseInt / ParseFloat like you said, or you could write a pretty simple regex to do the job.

Comment: Also worth considering `strconv.ParseFloat` will allow scientific notation which might be undesirable for your case: https://play.golang.org/p/uEaeWzucOq

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> I was thinking of using strconv ParseInt and ParseFloat but not sure
>   if that is the right way.

Well, it's certainly *a* right way.

You don't need to use ParseInt, though. ParseFloat will do the job.

```
func isNumeric(s string) bool {
    _, err := strconv.ParseFloat(s, 64)
    return err == nil
}
```

See an example here: https://play.golang.org/p/D53HRS-KIL

Comment: We just faced a bug with that. If you pass "inf" or "infinity" it returns an error: https://go.dev/play/p/94pIW4frlDD

Answer (score 6):

If you need to convert the string to a floating-point number `strconv.ParseFloat` is the first choice.
Here you just need to know that there is only `"0123456789"` and maximum one `'.'` in your string, here for me `isNumDot` is `12x` faster than `isNumeric`, see:
Consider this (1.7 seconds) - optimized for performance:

```
func isNumDot(s string) bool {
    dotFound := false
    for _, v := range s {
        if v == '.' {
            if dotFound {
                return false
            }
            dotFound = true
        } else if v < '0' || v > '9' {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

and this (21.7 seconds - doing more extra works "converts the string to a floating-point number"):

```
func isNumeric(s string) bool {
    _, err := strconv.ParseFloat(s, 64)
    return err == nil
}
```

---

Try it:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "time"
)

func isNumDot(s string) bool {
    dotFound := false
    for _, v := range s {
        if v == '.' {
            if dotFound {
                return false
            }
            dotFound = true
        } else if v < '0' || v > '9' {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}

func isNumeric(s string) bool {
    _, err := strconv.ParseFloat(s, 64)
    return err == nil
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(isNumDot("240"))     //true
    fmt.Println(isNumDot("abcd123")) //false
    fmt.Println(isNumDot("0.4."))    //false
    fmt.Println(isNumDot("240 "))    //false
    benchmark(isNumDot)
    benchmark(isNumeric)
}

func benchmark(f func(string) bool) {
    var res bool
    t := time.Now()
    for i := 0; i < 100000000; i++ {
        res = f("a 240") || f("abcd123") || f("0.4.") || f("240 ")
    }
    fmt.Println(time.Since(t))
    fmt.Println(res)
}
```

output:

```
true
false
false
false
1.7822s
false
21.723s
false
```

---

Using the benchmark (`isNumDot` is faster than `isNumeric`):

```
BenchmarkIsNumDot-8     34117197            31.2 ns/op         0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkIsNumeric-8     1931089           630 ns/op         192 B/op          4 allocs/op

// r = isNumDot("2.22")
BenchmarkIsNumDot-8     102849996           11.4 ns/op         0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkIsNumeric-8    21994874            48.5 ns/op         0 B/op          0 allocs/op

// r = isNumDot("a 240")
BenchmarkIsNumDot-8     256610877            4.58 ns/op        0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkIsNumeric-8     8962381           140 ns/op          48 B/op          1 allocs/op
```

The benchmark:

```
package main

import (
    "testing"
)

var r bool

func BenchmarkIsNumDot(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        r = isNumDot("a 240") || isNumDot("abcd123") || isNumDot("0.4.") || isNumDot("240 ")
    }
}

func BenchmarkIsNumeric(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        r = isNumeric("a 240") || isNumeric("abcd123") || isNumeric("0.4.") || isNumeric("240 ")
    }
}
```

Comment: If you benchmark something best use [go's build in benchmarking](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#pkg-overview)

Comment: @TehSphinX thanks for your comment, here it is obvious for me that `isNumDot` is faster than `isNumeric` because  `strconv.ParseFloat` doing more extra works "converts the string  to a floating-point number".

Answer (score 3):

I tried to comment on Adrian's answer but I guess I don't have enough reputation points. Building on his excellent response, here is a variation using PCRE. Some brief explanation on the symbols if you are unfamiliar with regular expressions:

"^" matches the start of input (i.e. beginning of your string)

"$" matches the end of input (i.e. the end of your string)

"()" are grouping operators

"*" matches 0 or more

"+" matches 1 or more

"?" matches exactly 0 or 1

"\d" is a character class which represents the character values 0 through 9

So, the following would require at least a leading 0, permit "0.", and everything else that is normally identified as a floating point value. You can experiment with this a bit.

```
func isFloat(s string) bool {
    return regexp.MatchString(`^\d+(\.\d*)?$`, s)
}
```

Naturally, if you are calling this function to validate data, it should be cleaned:

```
str := strings.TrimSpace(someString)
if isFloat(str) {
  ...
}
```

That only works on ASCII characters. If you are dealing with UTF8 or another multi-byte character set (MBCS), it can be done with regexp but more work would be required and perhaps another approach altogether.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `strconv.Atoi` function for check integer values, and the `strconv.ParseFloat` for float values. Below is an example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    v1 := "14"

    if _, err := strconv.Atoi(v1); err == nil {
        fmt.Printf("%q looks like a number.\n", v1)
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("%q is not a number.\n", v1)
    }

    v2 := "1.4"
    if _, err := strconv.ParseFloat(v2, 64); err == nil {
        fmt.Printf("%q looks like a float.\n", v2)
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("%q is not a float.\n", v2)
    }
}

/* Output:
"14" looks like a number.
"1.4" looks like a float.
*/
```

You can check it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/zbK2f21sTF).

Answer (score 2):

All the answers are valid, but there's another option not yet suggested:

```
re := regexp.MustCompile(`^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?$`)
isNum := re.Match([]byte("ab123"))
```

[Playground demo](https://play.golang.org/p/FaiGlmH6Pw)

Answer (score 0):

I hit this in a high-throughput system today and did a benchmark of the three suggestions.  Results:

BenchmarkNumDot-4: 657966132: 18.2 ns/op
BenchmarkNumeric-4: 49575919: 226 ns/op
BenchmarkRegexp-4: 18817201: 628 ns/op

Code follows since the playground does not support benchmarking.

```
package main

import (
    "regexp"
    "strconv"
    "testing"
)


func BenchmarkNumDot(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        isNumDot("abc")
    isNumDot("123")
    isNumDot("12.34")
    isNumDot("1.2.3.4")
    }
}

func BenchmarkNumeric(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        isNumeric("abc")
    isNumeric("123")
    isNumeric("12.34")
    isNumeric("1.2.3.4")
    }
}

func BenchmarkRegexp(b *testing.B) {
    re := regexp.MustCompile(`^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?$`)

    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        isNumReg("abc", re)
        isNumReg("123", re)
        isNumReg("12.34", re)
        isNumReg("1.2.3.4", re)
    }
}

func isNumDot(s string) bool {
    dotFound := false
    for _, v := range s {
        if v == '.' {
            if dotFound {
                return false
            }
            dotFound = true
        } else if v < '0' || v > '9' {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}

func isNumeric(s string) bool {
    _, err := strconv.ParseFloat(s, 64)
    return err == nil
}

func isNumReg(s string, re *regexp.Regexp) bool {
    return re.Match([]byte(s))
}
```